# Azure Speech SDK connection issue/error in unity

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, text-to-speech

I am using unity 2019.3 and installed latest azure speech SDKas far as I know. I also subscribed to pay as you go plan. Here is the error generated in unity:

```
CANCELED:
Reason=[Error]
ErrorDetails=[Connection was closed by the remote host. Error code: 1011. Error details: Internal server error. USP state: 3. Received audio size: 0bytes.]
Did you update the subscription info?
```

Comment: Can you post SSML that you have for Azure Speech?

Comment: I am not sure how. I have used the tutorial in :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/text-to-speech

Comment: For anybody having this issue I fixed it. It was a subscription bug, the free azure account couldn't save the speech service correctly so I had to upgrade my account to pay as you go then re enable the speed service. It probably happened because I used an old microsoft account to sign up into azure.

Comment: Azure Speech SDK error messages are messed up, and pretty cryptic. I am dealing with another type of message in SAME connection error GROUP. Really WHY MICROSOFT?